# Not to make 'nan' to '0' when reading the data through numpy.genfromtxt python

Tags: numpy, nan, genfromtxt

Now I am trying to read the array in the file named "filin1" such as:

```
filin1 = [1,3,4, ....,nan,nan,nan..] (in the file, actually it is just a column not an array like this)
```

So, I am trying to use numpy.genfromtxt as:

```
 np.genfromtxt(filin1,dtype=None,delimiter=',',usecols=[0],missing_values='Missing',usemask=False,filling_values=np.nan)
```

I expected to get [1,3,4, ....,nan,nan,nan..], but turned out to be:

```
[1,3,4, ....,0.,0.,0...]
```

I would like to hold 'nan' without converting it to '0.'.

Would you please give any idea or advice?

Thank you,
Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try to  simulate your case with a string input, I have no problem reading the `nan`

```
In [73]: txt=b'''1,2
3,4
1.23,nan
nan,02
'''
In [74]: txt=txt.splitlines()
In [75]: txt
Out[75]: [b'1,2', b'3,4', b'1.23,nan', b'nan,02']
In [76]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',')
Out[76]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  2.  ],
       [ 3.  ,  4.  ],
       [ 1.23,   nan],
       [  nan,  2.  ]])
```

`nan` is a valid float value

```
In [80]: float('nan')
Out[80]: nan
```

Your command works also, though it does

```
In [82]: np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=None,delimiter=',',usecols=[0],missing_values='Missing',usemask=False,filling_values=np.nan)
Out[82]: array([ 1.  ,  3.  ,  1.23,   nan])
```

Expecting the columns to contain integers (rather than float) could cause problems, since `nan` is a float, not int.

And missing values result in `nan` with both calls

```
In [91]: txt
Out[91]: [b'1,2', b'3,', b'1.23,nan', b'nan,02', b',']
```

Comment: Thank you. The results above happens in our school super computer and I also could read 'nan' in my personal laptop as you said. I think that it is related to the super computer system and python. I appreciate your check and advice.